# Separating an Integer

Tags: java, loops, integer

My question is how do I separate the digits in an integer? Below is the code I have and everything is how I want it minus the fact that I can't get the digits in the integer to separate. When I input "12345" currently the program outputs "12345" and I would like it to separate the digits so the output would be 1 2 3 4 5.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SNHU_Practice
{
    public static void main(String args[])
   {

       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = "";
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println( "Please enter a number: " );
        input = console.next();

        int i = 0;

        while( i < input.length() )
        {
            char temp = input.charAt(i);
            sum += Character.getNumericValue(temp);
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println( "The number entered was " + input + ". The sum     of these digits is: " + sum + "." );

    }
}
```

Comment: When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?

Comment: I think you should be clear what is your problem because your code [works](http://ideone.com/M8jxIt) for me

Comment: It doesn't fail, I just don't get the result I want. When I type in 12345, it returns 12345. I would like it to return 1 2 3 4 5, but am having difficulty in getting that to work. Everytime I come back to this issue I end up thinking in a giant circle and I can't figure out how to start the solution to my problem.

Comment: Your code [works fine](http://ideone.com/XYVnJd).

Comment: @Ph1shPhryd please provide an example of you expected output and output you are getting edit your question with details

Comment: Actually your `sum` is messed up, as you calculate the _char_ numeric value, that is different than the actual value of a number character.

Comment: @MouseEvent,
The sum is ok. Character.getNumericValue(char) returns the int value that the specified Unicode character represents. For example char '3'-> int 3

Comment: @davidh Unicode value of 3 is 51, see [here](https://ideone.com/o3X2sz).

Comment: @MouseEvent.
I have not told 
"Character.getNumericValue(char) returns the int Unicode value that the specified Unicode character represents"
but
"Character.getNumericValue(char) returns the int value that the specified Unicode character represents".

Forget the "unicode" term in the javadoc explanation if it misleads you.

Comment: Well, well, you're right.

Comment: @davidh But i still don't understand what the values other than numbers represents?

Comment: is this yet another homework-typed of question?

Comment: @davidh Look [here](https://ideone.com/fGNR0Q) as it returns 26 for 'q'. (I do note, q is the sixteenth letter).

Comment: @MouseEvent,
Interesting your example.Thank you.
In javadoc, we can read : The letters A-Z in their uppercase ('\u0041' through '\u005A'), lowercase ('\u0061' through '\u007A'), and full width variant ('\uFF21' through '\uFF3A' and '\uFF41' through '\uFF5A') forms have numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode specification, which does not assign numeric values to these char values. The value is related to the range of the letter in the alphabet. 'Q' is at the 17th place. From 10 to 26 inclusive, you have 17 places. The count is good but strange method...

Answer (score 0):

You can just write

```
input.replace("", " ").trim()
```

instead of `input` in `System.out.println`. E.g:

```
System.out.println( "The number entered was " + input.replace("", " ").trim() + ". The sum     of these digits is: " + sum + "." );
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class SNHU_Practice{
         public static void main(String args[]){

   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = "";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    int sum = 0;

    System.out.println( "Please enter a number: " );
    input = console.next();

    int i = 0;

    while( i < input.length() )
    {
        char temp = input.charAt(i);
        result.append(temp + " ");
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println( "The number entered was " + input + ". The output string is " + result + "." );

}
```

}